# Easier way to get extended information about Microsoft Security Updates?

Tags: windows-xp, security, windows-update

Part of my weekly routine involves setting aside often up to an hour to sift through the latest security updates from Microsoft, to determine which ones are actually worth considering and which ones (Fax Cover sheet vulnerabilities? Really?) are not relevant to my use cases.

This usually involves clicking on the "More information" link in the Windows XP Automatic Updates dialog for each Security Update and hotfix. This is necessary because the title of each update is simply "Security Update" and the abbreviated description that appears in the dialog is usually something along the lines of "A security issue has been identified that could allow a remote attacker to gain control over your system." So is of no help in evaluating the risk.

Has anyone heard of software or a system enhancement that makes this triage easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this page, lists all bulletins by Month with executive summaries for each.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/current.aspx

Comment: Not bad. At least it provides a more useful title. It would need an abstract to be truly useful.

Comment: Yes, you would actually have to go to each KB article to get more info. I suppose someone could write a program to gather this info and present it in a useful format, maybe MS has this for IT admins, not sure.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Works for me...